# Strumming all string but just one note. Something like Jimi Hendrix did

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, acoustic-guitar, rhythm, improvisation

Sometime ago I found a video on Youtube showing that strumming all strings but playing just one makes the improvisation/the rhythm a lot more 'richer'.
Now I see how amazing it's and I want to train, but I don't find much videos speaking of this... **Is there a name to refer this?**

I want exercices/tutorials of something like said on this video, by Paul Davids:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called *left hand muting* or *fretting hand muting*. You can mute with either hand, but when you're strumming with your picking hand it is not available to mute.

I'm not a fan of the presentation the guy makes in the video you linked, but at least he shows what he's doing. If you watch his hand, he always has one to three fingers spanned across all the strings. Those fingers are muting. If you mute behind the finger that's fretting, the fretted note will sound even though you have muting behind. You can also mute above and below the fretted string to isolate the note you want to hear.

I would practice muting all of the strings and strumming until you can get a clean *chick* sound and you can do the muting easily. Then try using just your third finger to fret notes while muting all the strings with your first and second fingers. Expand your muting and fretting practice and start to play actual riffs and songs with this technique.

I highly recommend when learning this technique that you learn thumb muting as he says in the video. To do it, you have to get your hand right up against the back of the guitar neck. There should be no gap at all, the web between your thumb and first finger should be totally touching the neck. You might find with this hand position that you can't easily play the low E string because it's too far away from your knuckles. You can either shift your hand just for those notes, or you can fret with your thumb! I prefer the latter.